# Trying to figure out regular expression in R for sub()

Tags: r

I'm trying to use regular expression in a sub() function in order to replace all the "\" in a Vector

I've tried a number of different ways to get R to recognize the "\":

- I've tried "`\\\`" but I keep getting errors.
- I've tried "`\.*`"
- I've tried "`\\\.*`"

```
data.frame1$vector4 <- sub(pattern = "\\\", replace = ", data.frame1$vector4)
```

The `\` that I am trying to get rid of only appears occasionally in the vector and always in the middle of the string. I want to get rid of it and all the characters that follow it.

The error that I am getting

> ```
> Error: '\.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "\."
> ```

Also I'm struggling to get Stack to print the "\" that I am typing above. It keeps deleting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) 4 backslashes** To insert backslash into an R literal string use a double backslash; however, a backslash is a metacharacter for a regular expression so it must be escaped by prefacing it with another backslash which also has to be doubled.  Thus using 4 backslashes will be needed in the regular expression.

```
s <- "a\\b\\c"
nchar(s)
## [1] 5
gsub("\\\\", "", s)
## [1] "abc"
```

**2) character class** Another way to effectively escape it is to surround it with [...]

```
gsub("[\\]", "", s)
## [1] "abc"
```

**3) fixed argument** Perhaps the simplest way is to use `fixed=TRUE` in which case special characters will not be regarded as regular expression metacharacters.

```
gsub("\\", "", s, fixed = TRUE)
## [1] "abc"
```

Comment: thank you. so to remove a single backslash with sub(), I should use 4 backslashes? cuz I tried using 3 and that didn't work, although that might not have been clear in what I typed above.

Comment: cuz when I type in 3 backslashes, Stack seems to remove one every time....

Comment: one of the character strings im trying to clean up looks like this:  "NO\xa0"

Comment: If you want to remove everything that is not a letter or number then `gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", "", x)`